# Need help understanding recursive function to generate all combinations of a string

Tags: javascript, recursion, combinations

I came across [this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/generating-all-combinations-of-an-array), but am having a hard time figuring out how the flow of this function is working.

```
function combinations(str) {
    var fn = function(active, rest, a) {
        if (!active && !rest)
            return;
        if (!rest) {
            a.push(active);
        } else {
            fn(active + rest[0], rest.slice(1), a);
            fn(active, rest.slice(1), a);
        }
        return a;
    }
    return fn("", str, []);
}
```

I've console.logged a bunch of statements, but I'm getting lost in the recursion. Specifically, I don't understand what's happening after the first of the two `fn`'s gets returned. It's simply returning `a`, but to me, it appears as if the second `fn` knows to take the returned `a`. How does that work? Shouldn't it need a variable assignment like so:

```
a = fn(active + rest[0], rest.slice(1), a);
fn(active, rest.slice(1), a);
```

Comment: please explain the downvote. I'm actually trying to figure out how it's working.

Comment: Take debugger and step through it.

Comment: *"Shouldn't it need a variable assignment"* - The `a` argument is an array, which means means (as with any object) that the function `a` is passed to can modify it, in this case by `.push()`ing additional elements into it. So every recursive call to `fn()` is operating on the same array. `fn()` only needs to return `a` after all the recursion is finished and it has a final result. If you're getting lost in the recursions try working it through on paper with a short string like `combinations("abc")`.

Comment: `a` is not the same in each iteration but all are bound to the Array that is passed the fist time around. The recursive function push to this Array in different depths and some return `a` and some just return undefined (default value when you just write `return;`. The original (non recursive) invocations `return a;` is the one that is returned and is the same that was passed in `[]`. If the outer function would have bound it it could just as well returned that instead of the result of the call. The whole thing is very imperative and poorly written.

Comment: Maybe for understanding the function, it's also important that `!active` is equivalent to `active == ""` when `active` is a string and that `rest[0]` is the same like `rest.charAt(0)` (the square bracket notation does not work in IE7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're trying to understand the specific algorithm, the key insight is the `a` variable accumulates the result *by reference* -- the lower level calls to `combinations()` push individual elements onto `a` and the function eventually returns accumulated result.

A good print statement can help understanding cases like this.  Here's the code with the addition of a print out that shows you what level of recursion you're at.  And I renamed `a` to `accum` to make it a bit more obvious:

```
function combinations(str) {
  var fn = function(active, rest, accum, level) {
    console.log(new Array(level).join('--'),
                ' active: \'' + active + '\'',
                'rest: \'' + rest + '\'',
                'accum:', accum);
    if (!active && !rest)
      return;
    if (!rest) {
      accum.push(active);
    } else {
      fn(active + rest[0], rest.slice(1), accum, level + 1);
      fn(active, rest.slice(1), accum, level + 1);
    }
    return accum;
  }
  return fn("", str, [], 1);
}
```

and the results:

```
combinations('abc')
  active: '' rest: 'abc' accum: []
--  active: 'a' rest: 'bc' accum: []
----  active: 'ab' rest: 'c' accum: []
------  active: 'abc' rest: '' accum: []
------  active: 'ab' rest: '' accum: [ 'abc' ]
----  active: 'a' rest: 'c' accum: [ 'abc', 'ab' ]
------  active: 'ac' rest: '' accum: [ 'abc', 'ab' ]
------  active: 'a' rest: '' accum: [ 'abc', 'ab', 'ac' ]
--  active: '' rest: 'bc' accum: [ 'abc', 'ab', 'ac', 'a' ]
----  active: 'b' rest: 'c' accum: [ 'abc', 'ab', 'ac', 'a' ]
------  active: 'bc' rest: '' accum: [ 'abc', 'ab', 'ac', 'a' ]
------  active: 'b' rest: '' accum: [ 'abc', 'ab', 'ac', 'a', 'bc' ]
----  active: '' rest: 'c' accum: [ 'abc', 'ab', 'ac', 'a', 'bc', 'b' ]
------  active: 'c' rest: '' accum: [ 'abc', 'ab', 'ac', 'a', 'bc', 'b' ]
------  active: '' rest: '' accum: [ 'abc', 'ab', 'ac', 'a', 'bc', 'b', 'c' ]
[ 'abc', 'ab', 'ac', 'a', 'bc', 'b', 'c' ]
```